# How to convert epoch time to date and time format in new columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unix-timestamp

I have a table with all the time columns in Unix epoch time format stored as varchar2(254). I want to create a new table haing two new columns for the date and time part of the timestamp in addition to the existing columns.

For example for a timestamp 1429152023, the two new columns will have the values 16 Apr 2015 and 02:40:23

I tried using `to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(1244108886,'SECOND')` but couldn't figure out a way to append the columns to the new table.

Comment: Why would you store date and time separately? Use the DATE datatype (which includes the time). And if you are still storing the epoch time, which value will you insert for new rows - maybe you want a virtual column? You said you want to add new column(s), but also say you want a new table, so it isn't clear quite what your goal is.

Comment: Hi Alex ! I want to add new columns adjacent to the existing columns in the new table one having the date and the other having the time part. I don't want to disturb the main table

Comment: But why two columns - how would you store the date and time then: both as varchar2 fields? With the date part as a DATE and the time as a varchar2, or an interval, or something else? How will new records be added to the new table, if you're keeping the old one? (Perhaps you really want a view rather than a new table?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Oracle DATE type contains both date and time elements, with precision down to the second. There is no reason to split a related date and time up into two columns; have a single column and extract the appropriate values for display only:

```
create table new_table (id, unixtime, realtime) as
select id, unixtime, date '1970-01-01' + unixtime/86400
from orig_table;

select id, unixtime,
  to_char(realtime, 'DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as realtime
from new_table;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7e12/2) (or [a slight variation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7e12/3) with the formatted date and time as two columns for display.)

You *could* split that into two VARCHAR2 columns:

```
create table new_table (id, unixtime, stringdate, stringtime) as
select id, unixtime,
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + unixtime/86400, 'DD Mon YYYY'),
  to_char(date '1970-01-01' + unixtime/86400, 'HH24:MI:SS')  
from orig_table;
```

([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4a51/1)) but you then wouldn't be able to easily compare values in different rows; keep the value as a DATE and only convert to a formatted string for display, at the last possible moment. Please do not store the date/time as a string, or split it into two strings. Use the proper data type.

You could also use a virtual column that converts the epoch time to a date on demand:

```
create table new_table (id number, unixtime varchar2(254),
  realtime generated always as (date '1970-01-01' + unixtime/86400));
```

and populate that with the values from your old table ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b010/1)), if you don't just want to add the virtual column to your original table.

Or you can use a view instead of a new table:

```
create view new_view (id, unixtime, realtime) as
select id, unixtime, date '1970-01-01' + unixtime/86400
from orig_table;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/044e9/1).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are after right?

Get date:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(a,'SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD') from a
```

Get time:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + numtodsinterval(a,'SECOND'),'HH24:MI:SS') from a
```